# Start Date should be less than End date validation in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I am using .net core to create the `StartDate`, `EndDate` of a `Term` which includes the `ClosureDate` that receives the report for that `Term`. Here I want a `StartDate`> `ClosureDate` and an `EndDate`<`ClosureDate`. And of course `StartDate`<`Enddate`. So here how should I test it? Process them right inside my `Repository` or use `scripts` to handle them at `View`?
Here is my Code:

**Repository**

```
 public bool CreateSemester(Semester semester)
    {
        if (CheckExistSemester(semester.SemesterName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var newSemester = new Semester
        {
            SemesterName = semester.SemesterName,
            SemesterStartDate = semester.SemesterStartDate,
            SemesterEndDate = semester.SemesterEndDate,
            ClosureDate = semester.ClosureDate
        };
        _dbContext.Semesters.Add(newSemester);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a custom validation.

Create a `CustomModelValidatorProvider` class.

```
 public class CustomModelValidatorProvider : IModelValidatorProvider
{

    public void CreateValidators(ModelValidatorProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Results.Any(v => v.Validator.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomModelValidator)) == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType == typeof(Semester))
        {
            context.Results.Add(new ValidatorItem
            {
                Validator = new MyCustomModelValidator(),
                IsReusable = true
            });
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomModelValidator : IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var model = context.Container as Semester;

       
        if (context.ModelMetadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime)
            && context.ModelMetadata.Name == nameof(model.SemesterStartDate))
            { 
      
        if (model.StartDate > model.ClosureDate)
        {
            return new List<ModelValidationResult>
                {
                   new ModelValidationResult("","Start Date should be less than Closure date")
                };
            }
        }
        if (context.ModelMetadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime)
            && context.ModelMetadata.Name == nameof(model.SemesterEndDate))
        {

            if (model.EndDate < model.ClosureDate)
            {
                return new List<ModelValidationResult>
                {
                   new ModelValidationResult("","End Date should be grater than Closure date")
                };
            }
        }
      
        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
    }
}
}
```

And in your `Startup`

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews(opt => opt.ModelValidatorProviders.Add(new CustomModelValidatorProvider()));
```

Test Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html). it's more flexible to define custom rules.

Following is the fluent validation example that you want to implement.

```
public class SearchValidator: AbstractValidator
{
  public SearchValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(m => m.StartDate)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Start Date is Required");

    RuleFor(m => m.EndDate)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
        .GreaterThan(m => m.StartDate.Value)
                        .WithMessage("End date must after Start date")
        .When(m => m.StartDate.HasValue);
  }
}
```

[here](https://onthefencedevelopment.com/2013/02/07/validating-startend-dates-fluent-validation-mvc-4/) is a well-explained article that will help you.

[here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/installation.html) is the documentation of fluent validation.